# Area of irregular similar hexagons

Tags: area, polygons

Irregular Hexagons $A$ and $B$ are geometrically similar. The shortest sides are $4$ inches and $3$ inches, respectively. If the area of hexagon $A$ is $48in^2$, what is the area of hexagon $B$?

I know the answer is $27 in^2$, but how do you get that?

Answer (score 2):

Because if corresponding linear dimensions of $A$ and $B$ are in $4:3$ ratio, then their areas are in $4^2:3^2$ ratio.

Answer (score 0):

The areas of similar figures vary in proportion to the square of the proportion by which the lengths are stretched. For example, a square  with one and one half times the side length has area $(3/2)^2$ as large.

Can you answer your question now?